# Cards dealt one at a time until first king appears. Find the probability that this occurs with the nth card dealt.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Cards are dealt from an ordinary deck of 52 playing cards one at a time until the first *king* appears. Find the probability that this occurs with the *nth* card dealt.

My approach:

n=1: ${4\over 52}$

n=2: ${48\over 52}$ * ${4\over 51}$

n=3: ${48\over 52}$ * ${47\over 51}$ * ${4\over 50}$

n=4: ${48\over 52}$ * ${47\over 51}$ * ${46\over 50}$ * ${4\over 49}$

n=5: ${48\over 52}$ * ${47\over 51}$ * ${46\over 50}$ * ${45\over 49}$ * ${4\over 48}$

However, I am having trouble constructing a general form. This is what I have so far:

In general:

${48\over 52}$ * ${48-n+2\over 51}$ * ... * ${48-n+2\over 52-n+2}$ * ${4\over 52-n+1}$ * ... * ${1\over 5}$ * 1

But it seems like it only works for n ≧ 2

Could you please help me from here? Thank you so much!

Comment: [A MathJax and $\LaTeX$ tutorial can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The notation of [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) is quite useful here.  $\dfrac{48\frac{n-1}{~}\cdot 4}{52\frac{n}{~}}$

Comment: Thank you! However, it is still not showing up correctly and I have tried a few formats such as {4\over 52}

Comment: To write $\frac{a}{b}$, type \frac{a}{b} between dollar signs.  To type $\binom{n}{k}$, type \binom{n}{k} between dollar signs.

Comment: `$\frac{4}{52}$` produces $\frac{4}{52}$.  Make the fraction bigger by using \dfrac instead.  Things must be enclosed in dollar signs to be parsed by the MathJax interpreter.  Enclose it in double dollar signs to have it appear on it's own line:  `$$\text{myownline}$$` produces $$\text{myownline}$$ Additional functions and formats and such are explained in the link I gave earlier.  Also, be mindful of using curly braces.  `$a^bcd$` produces $a^bcd$ whereas `$a^{bcd}$` produces $a^{bcd}$

Comment: @JMoravitz How did you type the highlighted format that allows you to type the actual code without compiling the code?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Enclose it in... actually... what is that symbol called?  Like an apostrophe to the left of the $1$ on most keyboards.  The one that produces a tilde if you held shift...   ` not '.  Single quote?  [This answer suggests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/what-is-the-name-for-these-keys-on-a-computer-keyboard) it is called the grave accent or backtick.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, backtick is the normal term in computing science. Grave accent would be better in a linguistics context.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your $n=4$ case, note that $48\cdot 47 \cdot 46=\frac {48!}{45!}$ so your general form becomes $$\frac {48!}{(49-n)!}\cdot 4\cdot \frac {(52-n)!}{52!}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative approach, let's say the first King appears on the card $T$.

Then $T>n$ if and only if cards $1,2,3, \dots , n$ are non-Kings, so
$$P(T>n) = \frac{\binom{48}{n}}{\binom{52}{n}}$$
To find $P(T=n)$, use $$P(T=n) = P(T>n-1) - P(T>n)$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you get _P(T_ > n), especially $\binom{48}{n}$ . Thanks!

Comment: There are $\binom{52}{n}$ possible combinations of $n$ cards drawn from the deck of $52$, all of which we assume are equally likely.  Of these, $\binom{48}{n}$ consist entirely of the $48$ non-Kings.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you!